# Why is Math.floor needed to generate a random number between x and y?

Tags: javascript

Why do you need to use Math.floor() when trying to generate a random number between 2 other numbers in js? I can't seem to get it to work just like this: Math.random() * ((y-x)+1) + x)

Comment: `Math.random() * <anything>` will give you some random *number*, not an integer. If you want an integer, use `Math.floor`

Comment: In your code, you need a `floor` because you're incorrectly doing `+ 1` on your difference, causing it to return values `> y`. If you remove the `+ 1`, all values will be `>= x && < y`

Answer (score 2):

According to the MDN docs,

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
>   number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1).

This means that the number you will be returned is between 0 and 1. Now, having a long bunch of decimals points isn't super user friendly for us developers so we like to multiply it by a certain value, add one (since the random function return a number between 0 and 1 but *excluding* 1), and round down the number in order to achieve an integer that is easy to read and work with.

For example:

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

This takes the number generated by "Math.random()", let's say that value is 0.12345, and then multiplies it by 10 which gives a result of 1.2345. We then add 1 to have a value of 2.2345. Now, all those decimal points aren't very useful to us since we want a nice round number, therefore we call the Math.floor() method which round down the value to a value of 2.

Again, the Math.floor method is called so we don't have to worry about all those decimal points and are instead given a nice round integer.

Comment: What if you are looking for a random number between 2 numbers and actually want decimals? Is there a way to code that with Math.random or would you simply make a function with if statements and only returns numbers within a certain range? Thanks for the help, I'm rather new to programming.

Comment: @josh scale [0,1) as mentioned: a+(b-a)*Math.random() would give you decimals between a (inclusive) and b (exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` will generate a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). This usually means that have a number with a lot of decimal places, which isn't very user-friendly. To convert it to an Integer, you will need to use `Math.floor()` (converts number to nearest Integer less than it) or `Math.ceil()` (converts number to nearest Integer larger than it).

```js
console.log(Math.random());
```

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 5;
var random;
console.log((random = Math.random() * (y-x)+1 + x));
console.log("Nearest Integer less than random: "+Math.floor(random));
```

To get a random integer between x (inclusive) and y (exclusive):

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

To get a random number between x and y (not necessarily an integer), just remove `Math.floor()`:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Demo:

```html
Min:
<input type="number" id="min">
<br/>
Max:
<input type="number" id="max"/><br/>
<button onClick="generateRandom()">
Generate Random Number
</button>
<p/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function generateRandom(){
 var min = parseFloat(document.getElementById('min').value);
 var max = parseFloat(document.getElementById('max').value);
 if(!isNaN(min)&&!isNaN(max)&&min<max){
 document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Random Number: '+getRndInteger(min, max);
  } else {
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<b>Please enter valid min and max values.</b>';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I failed to mention, but I was wondering if you're looking for non-int numbers. Say, between 5.03 and 8.339342. I couldn't get code to work for that without Math.floor(), which mitigates the point I was trying to solve. Is there a way without Math.floor() or Math.ceil()?

Comment: @josh I have added an example of how to get a random number between two numbers x and y.